# TabActivity vs FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-tabactivity

I wonder what is the advantage of using Fragments(the new version of ActivityGroup) As for now I can do the same with TabActivity. If I want to replace the fixed tabwidget I can set visibility to gone and to change tabActivites I can use setCurrentTab(int c) in the onClick event of my custom layout. Could you tell me a motivation to use FragmentActivities instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TabActivity is depricated. See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

In my opinion the transition towards FragmentActivity is a good move for the community, offering a simpler designed approach to "fragmenting" activities and the views they contain.